# How to filter an array and remove duplicated elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm mapping data from an array and some of the data have the same name so I would like to display them only once and not multiple time. I'm using React and here's the api [link](https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/machine).

Here's my code (it's just a simple map) :

```
{machines.filter((machines) => {
  if (search === "") {
    return machines
  } else if (machines.move.name.replace(/-/g, ' ').toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())) {
    return machines
  }
})
.map((ma) => 
                                        
  <tr key={ma?.id} className='machines_table_body_row'>
    <td className='machines_table_body_row_name'>
      {ma?.item?.name.toUpperCase()}
    </td>
    <td className='machines_table_body_row_element'>
      <Link
        to={`/moves/${ma?.move?.name}`}
        key={ma?.move?.name}
      >
        {ma?.move?.name.replace(/-/g, ' ')}
      </Link>
    </td>
  </tr>
)}
```

What I'd like is having the first  with tm01, tm02, tm03, etc only once and the second  with all the different attacks (but here also without repetitions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a filtered array and then map on it. Below is how to create that filtered array :

```js
const filtredMachines = [];
machines.forEach(ma => {
  if(!filtredMachines.some(m=>m.move.name === ma.move.name)){
     filtredMachines.push(ma)
  }
})
```

Comment: Thx it works. Can you tell me where the 'm' parameter comes from ? Is it to avoid doing ma.move.name === ma.move.name ?

Comment: Yeah it is to avoid that. I need machine items inside the `forEach` and the `some` function, and I need two different names. That is why I picked `ma` and `m`. You could name them as you want.

Comment: So what the code is doing is checking each item in the array and looking for its name. If the name is not the same than the previous item it push it in the map otherwise it prevents it from being mapped ?

Comment: For each item inside `machines` array, it looks if there is an item inside `filtredMachines` array that has the same name, if it's not the case, it pushes it inside the `filteredArray`.

Comment: Ok thx for the good explanation :)

Comment: Really glad I could help !

Comment: The suggested approaches above comes with more time complexities as for each item it is checking throughout the array, making it O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

This function will remove any duplicated items from a given list, going by the property you pass to it. I prefer avoiding using `forEach` to keep the code immutable.

```
const yourList = [
  { name: "la", id: 2 },
  { name: "blah", id: 3 },
  { name: "blah", id: 4 },
];

const uniqueByfield = (list, field) =>
  list.reduce((acc, item) => {
    return acc.some((accItem) => accItem[field] === item[field])
      ? acc
      : [...acc, item];
  }, []);

const result = uniqueByfield(yourList, "name");

console.log(result); // removes the item with id 4
```